# "AddCustomer" was not declared in this scope. Where is the mistake?

Tags: c++, database, oop

My aim is to develop a database for Customer, so that I started creating a Datbase.h, Database.cpp and the classical main.cpp.
When I run i received the following error:

*"AddCustomer" was not declared for this scope*

In Database.cpp you find only an example.
I am convinced there is something in the class that doesn't work well, but I don't know.
Where is the mistake according to you?
Many thanks, I am becoming crazy

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

#include "Database.cpp"

int main()
{
int choice;

//creating a menu for Database
cout<<"\t1. Add new customer"<<endl;
cout<<"\t2. Search Database for Customer"<<endl;
cout<<"\t3. Clear File"<<endl;
cout<<"\t4. Edit File "<<endl;
cout<<"\t5. Exit Program"<<endl;

cin>>choice;

switch (choice){
    case 1:
        AddCustomer();
        break;
        
    case 2: 
        break; 
//...
        
  }
}
```

Database.cpp

```
#include "Database.h"

using namespace std; 

Database::Database(){ 
}

void Datbase::AddCustomer(){
cout<< "It works"<<endl //it's an example 
}

void Datbase:: searchname(){
}

void Datbase:: searchmail(){
}

void Datbase:: searchcell(){
}

void Datbase:: quit(){
}

void Datbase:: displayall(){
}

void Datbase:: search(){
}

void Datbase:: deleteFile(){
}

void Datbase:: editFile(){
}
```

Database.h

```
#ifndef DATABASE_H_INCLUDED
#define DATABASE_H_INCLUDED

#endif // DATABASE_H_INCLUDED

 class Database 
  {

 public: 

    Database();
    void AddCustomer(); 
    void searchname(); 
    void searchemail(); 
    void searchcell(); 
    void quit(); 
    void displayall(); 
    void search(); 
    void deleteFile(); 
    void editFile(); 
 };
```

Comment: you should not include a source file. Instead include the header and then link the compiled sources

Comment: So, in main.cpp do I change "Database.cpp" with "Database.h"?

Comment: also, `AddCustomer` is a method, you need to create a `Database` object to be able to call it.

Comment: could you give me a practical example? It's my first time I use oop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to the reason that you have used AddCustomer() inside the case of switch statement, which the compiler is expecting to be avaialble in the global scope, hence can't find it.

Since it's a member function of the Database class, you will need to access it through an object. For eg.

```
int main()
{
int choice;
Database db;

cin>>choice;

switch (choice){
    case 1:
        db.AddCustomer();
        break;
        
    case 2: 
        break; 
//...
        
  }
}
```

Also you should include the header, not the cpp file directly.

And, if you want to use it without declaring an object (doesn't seem to be your case though), you can make the member function static to the class, and then access as

```
Database::AddCustomer()
```

Comment: Yes that is because you can access the function using an instance of the Database class.

Comment: Also, when the compiler says it doesn't find something in a 'scope', you should first look if it is a member function, then access using an object; though there can be due to simple typos also, like missing a semicolon then compiler will not be able to identify a following function definition.

Also the same applies to variables (though global variables should be used when you know for sure it's better like that, big projects generally won't have global variables)

Comment: I can't understand how to sort out the problem. I have included "Database.h" at the top of the main and after...

Comment: Add a

// creating an object named 'db' of the class  Database


```  Database db;   ``` 

then access AddCustomer like this ->


```    db.AddCustomer();    ```



It should work, if needed dm me at https://mobile.twitter.com/AdityaGupta150
There you can send the picture of error too, ok to help :D

Comment: @MacUser You asked a practical example in comments, see this

```    class DataBase{
             public:   void AddRow(){ /*logic to add row*/      }
}

int main(){
     DataBase mydata;

     mydata.AddRow();
}

This is how you access a `member function`, the functions defined inside the class/struct, also this is called the 'dot operator' if you want to see more you can search that

Comment: So I have to copy what I've written in Database.h at the top of the main?

Comment: Not needed, it should work like that too.

Since, what #include actually does is it just copies the content of Database.h at top of the main.cpp file

Comment: @MacUser Did you sort out the problem ?

Comment: No, I haven't but I'm finding a solution using your advices

Comment: Wait how are you compiling it ?

You need to compile both main.cpp and Database.cpp at once, else it will show a "linked error" similar to that (Undefined Reference to ...)

Comment: Build: Debug in DataCustomer (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Comment: This is what CodeBlocks returns

Comment: One of these might help, see i think you `may` be doing wrong with the multiple files in codeblock

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qR2aS6t9-8k
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rpipDcG8GMg

One is for C code, but your code will work fine with it

Comment: Now I receive this errror: statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function

Comment: This is then other than the topic here actually.

But, you may get such error if you used templates, OR maybe you just called the function with different argument, like calling AddCustomer(4), while AddCustomer is defined such that it requires NO argument, so you may need to change the definition `in this case` to AddCustomer(int) etc.
*Note -> The error messages depend on compilers

Comment: Have you understood it ?
If not you may just un-accept my answer, the question may get better answer by someone else :D